# Wrong index chosen by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

1. why i got `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` in my
   explain cmd because it slow down my query **1.3s** .

explain :

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                                     | key                 | key_len | ref                         | rows  | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lieuexecut1_ | ref    | fk_ao_lieuex,fk_region_lieuex,idao_idregion_index | idao_idregion_index | 5       | const                       | 27343 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appeloffre0_ | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                           | PRIMARY             | 4       | ao.lieuexecut1_.appel_offre |     1 |                                                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+-----------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

2. Why when i force the use of index `fk_ao_lieuex` of my foreing key `use index ( fk_ao_lieuex)`  the query run fast **0.0x s** .

explain

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref                            | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | appeloffre0_ | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY      | 4       | NULL                           |   10 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | lieuexecut1_ | ref   | fk_ao_lieuex  | fk_ao_lieuex | 4       | ao.appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

here is my query :

```
select  .... from ao.appel_offre appeloffre0_ 
inner join ao.lieu_execution lieuexecut1_ 
on appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE=lieuexecut1_.appel_offre 
where lieuexecut1_.region=1
group by appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE 
order by appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE desc 
limit 10
```

my indexes of table `lieu_execution`

```
+----------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+-
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |
+----------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+-
| lieu_execution |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id          | A         |       62127 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| lieu_execution |          1 | fk_ao_lieuex        |            1 | appel_offre | A         |       62127 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| lieu_execution |          1 | fk_province_lieuex  |            1 | province    | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| lieu_execution |          1 | fk_region_lieuex    |            1 | region      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| lieu_execution |          1 | fk_ville_lieuex     |            1 | ville       | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| lieu_execution |          1 | idao_idregion_index |            1 | region      | A         |         227 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| lieu_execution |          1 | idao_idregion_index |            2 | appel_offre | A         |         227 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
+----------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+-
```

Comment: You need to have a composite index that includes both `appel_offre` and `region` columns at first. Add it and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I update it but he still chose the wrong index and even when i force it to chose the composite index the query get executed slowly.

Comment: Change the order of fields in the index. `region` should go first

Comment: it chose it but the query run slow.

Comment: What is "slow"? What is the execution plan for the "fast" one?

Comment: Yep, I see now. Mysql is not smart enough to get that you just need  10 rows that are ordered by a plain value, not aggregate. Let's think what you could do then...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68191/discussion-between-zerkms-and-youssef).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Create a composite `(region, appel_offre)` index
2. You change your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses to use `lieuexecut1_.appel_offre` column instead.

It improves the performance because now `mysql` optimizer has a chance to use the just created index for both using it in `lieuexecut1_.region=1` predicate and further `GROUP BY` and sorting. Otherwise it must do everything before applying `LIMIT` hence it's slow.

Comment: just one thing @zerkms in the slow query you said that group by/order by is done over a column that is not covered by a index that is currently used why that ? because `group by appeloffre0_.ID_APPEL_OFFRE` is a PK so it's a index and it's used

Comment: @Youssef: no, it's used to satisfy a join condition. Only the index for the primary table can be used to optimize group by's